# What to do with spammers in the tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, editing, tag-wiki

Just now I found spam in the tag wiki (suggested edits), but I couldn't flag the post as spam - just reject it as vandalism. Does this *vandalism* rejection end up in moderator log somewhere or does it disappear in cyber space?

Just curious...

[image: tag wiki edit suggested]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the moderators are in chat, @ reply to us with a link to the edit/user profile and tell us what's up.

Otherwise just reject it. If it's a single edit it doesn't matter much; there's nothing a 1 rep spam user can really do without any peer review (aside from spam in their own profile description, which isn't a problem really). If it's lots of edits, still reject them (on the off chance someone accepts them mistakenly/with good intentions...or bad ones) but definitely ping one of the mods in chat and we can suspend/destroy the account.

Generally spammers are one-off so a single rejection or two is enough. In this case I've gone and destroyed the user though; they were clearly just a spammer.

Comment: Thanx Ben. Now I know! :-)